# Handling clients with static IP from different network

Tags: router, openwrt, dnsmasq

I have to set up a wireless router (with openwrt) whose dnsmasq DHCP server is configured to issue addresses on the 10.109.0.0/16 network.  Now the challenge is that there are a few machines on the network who are unfortunately statically configured to have IP addresses in 192.168.1.0/24.  Is there a way to make those 192.168.1.x machines reachable from machines on the 10.109.x.x network?

Or would that be too much trouble and it would be a much easier solution to try hard and change either the network of the 192.x machines or maybe reconfigure the router to work on the 192 network?

Answer (score 0):

While a bit messy, having two subnets on the same link shouldn't cause any problems.

Just configure the router's LAN interface to have IP addresses `10.109.0.1/16` **and** `192.168.1.1/24` (or whatever gateway those machines expect).

Of course, DHCP will always give addresses out of the main subnet (unless you add static leases for individual off-subnet hosts).

Comment: This feature is usually called "Secondary IP address" and relates to the internal (LAN) port. Depending on the router's OS, you might need an additional route and/or policies to allow inter-subnet traffic. Or it just might work immediately.